# img element won't add class when radio button is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 5 radio buttons and 5 images. I want, when clicked, each button to show a specific image. However, when I check the radio button with something else, it adds another image instead of replacing it!

Here's the code

https://jsfiddle.net/fcd8s9c8/5/

Here's my JS code

```
$("#ekoloshki").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#ekoloshkislika").removeClass("skrijgo");
    }
    else    {
        $("#ekoloshkislika").addClass("skrijgo");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the id from the currently checked radio button and concatenate it with the word `slika`.

```
$('img').addClass('skrijgo');
$('img#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'slika').removeClass('skrijgo');
```

*I've added images to illustrate*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="karta"]').change(function() {
    $('img').addClass('skrijgo');
    $('img#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'slika').removeClass('skrijgo');
  });
});
```

```css
#listata {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  background-color: white;
}

.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  height: 5%;
}

.skrijgo {
  display: none;
}

#kartata {
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: relative;
  float: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="listata">
  <div id="checkboxes" class="unselectable">
    <label><input type="Radio" id="ekoloshki" name="karta">Еколошки фактори</label>
    <p>
    <label><input type="Radio" id="socio" name="karta">Социо-економски фактори</label>
    <p>
    <label><input type="Radio" id="prirodni" name="karta">Природно-географски фактори</label>
    <p>
    <label><input type="Radio" id="infra" name="karta">Инфраструктурни фактори</label>
    <p>
    <label><input type="Radio" id="site" name="karta">Сите фактори</label>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Kartite -->
<section>
  <div id="kartata">
    <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg" id="ekoloshkislika" class="skrijgo">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhILUOq_dTGoC4-EqYrk25I3G3RuQkz09hgqABMs9AOg2h-dumkA" id="socioslika" class="skrijgo">
    <img src="http://lmsotfy.com/so.png" id="prirodnislika" class="skrijgo">
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/785/1*H-25KB7EbSHjv70HXrdl6w.png" id="infraslika" class="skrijgo">
    <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/586aaf811fdce414493f5105.png" id="siteslika" class="skrijgo">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not a problem yet but if OP ever adds any transitions to the `skrijgo` class, then adding it to all images first then removing one could cause unwanted visual side-effects.

Comment: Thank you so very much! This did the job brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to add the `skrijgo` class to all the other images that you don't want to show.

I'd go with a more generic solution. For example

```
$('input[name="kartka"][id]').on('change', function() {
  let checkId = `${this.id}slika`
  $('#kartata img').each((i, elt) => {
    elt.classList.toggle('skrijgo', elt.id !== checkId)
  })
})
```

That is, whenever an input named *"kartka"* (with an `id` attribute) changes, iterate over all the `<img>` elements inside `#kartata` and if their `id` attribute matches the radio button's `id + 'slika'` , then remove the class. If not, then add the class.